# Remove focus from a EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have two `EditText`s and one `CheckBox` and a `Button` in my layout in the above order. After entering the values to the `EditText`, the user has to accept terms and conditions by clicking the `Checkbox`. I need to remove focus from `EditText`s after the checkbox is clicked. Right now the focus is always on the second `EditText`. How can this be achieved? Please help.
**Layout**:

```
  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/pm_et_customer_id"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ems="10"
      android:hint="@string/customer_id_hint"
      android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:inputType="phone"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/pm_rl_mob_no_widget"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="6dp"
      android:layout_below="@id/pm_et_customer_id"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pm_et_dial_code"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pm_et_msisdn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:ems="3"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/plus_nine_one"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pm_et_msisdn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pm_et_dial_code"
        android:ems="9"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/msisdn_hint"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:maxLength="14"/>
  </RelativeLayout>

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/pm_bt_proceed"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/lay_t_c"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
      android:text="@string/bt_label_proceed"/>

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/pm_rl_mob_no_widget"
      android:id="@+id/lay_t_c"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/pm_check_t_and_c"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="@string/pm_label_accept"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pm_tv_t_and_c"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="@string/pm_label_t_and_c"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>
  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just clear your focus on `Check Box` click.

Comment: @bearded beast what is  sequence of your views in layout?

Comment: @jaydroider its giving focus to first EditText

Comment: @beardedbeast Give your `EditText2.clearFocus()`.

Comment: @Dhiraj EditText1->EditText2->CheckBox->Button

Comment: @jaydroider tried like this " if (msisdnET.hasFocus()) msisdnET.clearFocus();
        if (customerIdEt.hasFocus()) customerIdEt.clearFocus(); "

Comment: @beardedbeast Post your XML code.

Comment: @beardedbeast Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

> Using `onCheckedChangeListener` of `Check Box` you can do this. Just apply this on your `Activity's onCreate()`

```
chb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pm_check_t_and_c);
        chb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (chb1.isChecked()) {
                    edt1.clearFocus();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edt1.getWindowToken(), 0);
                } else {
                    edt1.requestFocus();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: is it working or not ?

Answer (score 1):

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setFocusable(false);
        }
    });
```

Add above OnClickListener to check box.

Comment: if I do like this I won't be able to edit the EditText again.

Comment: set `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to most outer layout. and call `editText.clearFocus();` inside check box OnClickListener. Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.setFocusable(false);
        }
    });
```

After removing  focus, please do one more..

> `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);`

Answer (score -3):

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
```

Use it on Checkbox listner it worked for me

Comment: if I do this , I won't be able to edit it again.

Comment: before editing put this line editText.setEnabled(false);

Comment: it simply disables the edittext, and you cant edit at all